# How to change the label text in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, label, legend

I am learning r and I have problems with setting the label text(desired text) and adjust the size and bold fond for the legend title. I tried to find some help from other sources in stackoverflow and it requires to put `scale_color_hue` to change the label text but I have no idea where to put it. Here is my dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  class = c("a","a","b","b","c","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"))
```

Here is my code to make change:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
  filter(time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner")) %>%
  droplevels %>%
  count(time, class) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(class,prop), y = prop, fill = time, label = scales::percent(prop))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.5, size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="vertical")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Time",nrow = 1))+
  coord_flip()
```

For the title `Time` I can set to change it to our desired text but I dont know how to set its fond size and also to set it to bold. For the label text like `Breakfast` and `Dinner` I cannot set it to the desired text.

Any help for this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Put `face="bold"` in `theme(..., legend.title=element_text(.***.))`

Comment: How about changing the text label? Do you have any idea?

Comment: In the legend the label ```Dinner``` and ```Breakfast``` I want to replace them with the text we wish

Comment: `+ scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Label 1","Label 2"))`

Comment: I edited the way to put legend title so where should I put the face="bold" in?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I edited ```guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Time",nrow = 1))``` this so where should I put the face="bold"

Comment: Could you please say how you want the legend text to be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bold legend title, add face="bold" in the theme.
For the legend labels, use `scale_fill_discrete(labels=...)`.

So,

```
...
  theme(..., legend.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold", size=14)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Label 1","Label 2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of choices depending on what you want to achieve.

This answer only addresses your question about the legend title.

The typical way to include the legend title is by naming the aesthetic used for grouping the legend keys in the `ggplot::labs` function like so `labs(fill = "Time")`.
The other way as @Edward has pointed out is using `theme`

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  class = c("a","a","b","b","c","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"))


library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)


g0 <- dat %>% 
  filter(time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner")) %>%
  droplevels %>%
  count(time, class) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(class, prop), y = prop, fill = time, label = scales::percent(prop))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.5, size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  coord_flip()

g1 <- g0+
  labs(fill = "Time")+
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

g1


g2 <- g0+
  labs(fill = "Time")+
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 20))
g2
```

g1 which gives you:

[image]

And g2 gives you:

[image]